# Assign values according to parameter verilog

Tags: verilog

I have a parameter `WIDTH = n`, can I assign a value to another parameter VALUE such that `VALUE = {1'b1, WIDTH-1{1'b0}}`?

For example:

```
parameter WIDTH = 8;
parameter VALUE = {1'b1, (WIDTH-1){1'b0}};
```

So basically VALUE will have 1000_0000;

Answer (score 0):

You need another set of `{}`.

```
parameter VALUE = {1'b1, {WIDTH-1{1'b0}}};
```

You can also do

```
parameter VALUE = 32'b1 << WIDTH-1;
```

Which one you pick depends if you care about the actual bit-width of VALUE.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, you are missing a } in your first answer. But I got your point though, Thanks!

Comment: If you care about the bit-width of `VALUE`, the you can specify the range in the definition. Ex.: `parameter [15:0] VALUE = {1'b1, (WIDTH-1){1'b0}};`